# How can I create an @Entity without a @Version field using Spring Roo?

Tags: java, spring-roo

I am using Spring Roo with JPA (Hibernate) for my entity model. I don't want to have a @Version field in some entities. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

After the generation of entity, before exiting roo shell,  modify entity java source file with the following

```
    @RooJpaActiveRecord(...... ,versionField = "")
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using below annotation in roo

```
@RooJpaEntity(versionField = "",
              identifierColumn = "YOUR_DATABASE_FILEDNAME",
              identifierField = "YOUIDNAME")
```

Answer (score 1):

Roo [entity command](http://www.springsource.org/roo/guide?w=command-index#command-index-entity-commands) takes `--versionField` and '--versionColumn' parameters. I think setting `--versionField=""` should do the trick for you.

Comment: I tried with --versionField "" (extra = cause syntax error), the generated XXX_Roo_Entity.aj still has field version, thus I think we can't hide it at least in the current Roo version 1.1.1. - Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular reason to remove `@Version` from a Roo entity, it saves the hassle of concurrent data modification issues which you might encounter with a distributed web application.

Comment: existing database without version column?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Like @J-16SDiZ said, what if you're using a legacy database?